# MATLAB: Calculating the average value of elements across every second page in a 3D array

Tags: matlab

I have a 10x7x10000 MATLAB array. Thus the array has 10 rows, 7 columns, and 10000 pages.

I seek to create two 10x7 summary arrays in the following way.

**First summary array.** Cell A1 should be the average value that is in A1 on the 1st, 3rd, 5th, ..., 9999th pages. Cell B1 should the same except for the average value that is in B1 on those pages, and so on the for other 68 cells of this summary array.

**Second summary array.** Cell A1 should be the average value that is in A1 on the 2nd, 4th, 6th, ..., 10,000th pages. Then repeat the same for the other cells of the summary array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average/mean can be obtained with the function `mean` which takes the dimension onto which perform the operation as second parameter (in your case `3`). 
You can use it in combination with the semicolon (or range) operator `:` to specify which slices of your matrix to use. 
For example:

```
A1 = mean(A(:,:,1:2:end), 3);
A2 = mean(A(:,:,2:2:end), 3);
```